# no icon on BottomTabNavigator after updating to Expo 40

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, jsx

after updating expo to version 40 from version 37, I no longer see the Icons, they are invisible somehow.

I found topics with similar issues but none of the solutions worked for me. I read that I needed to replace navigationOptions by defaultNavigationOptions however this did not solve the issue.

Any one have an idea how I can fix that?

```
const tabNavigator = TabNavigator.createStyles();

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Overview: {
      resetOnBlur: true,
      screen: OverviewStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home",
      },
    }, 

    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStack,
      resetOnBlur: true,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Settings",
      },
    },

  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: true,
      labelStyle: {},
      hidden: true,
      activeBackgroundColor: Colors.navigationBkgdActive,
      activeTintColor: Colors.navigationColorActive,
      inactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.navigationBkgd,
      inactiveTintColor: Colors.navigationColor,
      backgroundColor: Colors.navigationColor,
      labelBottomStyle: {
        fontSize: Fonts.bodyFontSizeSmall,
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.navigationBkgd,
        height: 64,
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
      },
    },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
        const icons = {
          Overview: "home-outline",
          Settings: "settings",

        };

        const style = focused ? tabNavigator.activeTab : {};

        return (
          <View style={tabNavigator.container}>
            <View style={style} />
                <Icon
                style={[
                  tabNavigator.icon,
                  { color: focused ? "#D97D54" : "lightgray" },
                ]}
                size={28}
                name={icons[navigation.state.key]}
              />
          </View>
        );
      },
      showIcon: true,
    }),
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with icons, mines related to the settings icon. I cannot see you import statements but this is what I did in the end.

Before which originally worked on EXPO 38 SDK but doesn't on EXPO 42 SDK:

```
// Import Statements...
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

// Further down in TabNavigator code...
<MaterialCommunityIcons name="settings" size={28} color={tintColor} />
```

After upgrading to EXPO 42 SDK:

```
// Import Statements...
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

// Further down in TabNavigator code...
<MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-settings" size={28} color={tintColor} />
```

According to the list of [Material Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/), it appears that "settings" has been renamed to to "cog" but I wanted to change mine to look more like "account-cog", So I highly recommend you look through and identify which Icons you want as they may have been renamed.